# Parsing nested JSON using HiveQL

Tags: json, hive, hiveql

I have the following nested JSON format data stored as syslog which I need to query using HiveQL and convert into a CSV file (which would be used to display a graph) :

```
"logAggregate": {"name-1":{"time":"74","count":"1"},"name-2":{"time":"2","count":"1"},"name-3 {"time":"2","count":"5"},"name-4":{"time":"22","count":"1"},
 。
 。
 。// and so on..
 。}
```

The output format I am looking for is something like below:

```
name-1 time
name-2 time
name-3 time
.
.
. // so on
```

I am relatively new to Hive so not sure how I should parse this JSON data.
I tried fiddling with Lateral View and json_tuple but in vain!

Any help would be much apppreciated!

Comment: You can use a `json-serde` to define the table and load the data. The details are [here](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde). Try this and update the question if you facing any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this blog entry ( http://brickhouseconfessions.wordpress.com/2014/02/07/hive-and-json-made-simple/ ) which describes using the JSON UDF's provided in Brickhouse ( http://github.com/klout/brickhouse ).

For your specific case, you probably want to parse as a map, and then do an explode on the map.

```
SELECT key,
map_index( value, "time") as time_value
FROM my_table
LATERAL VIEW explode_map( from_json( json, 'map<map<string,string>>') ) kv1 as k, v;
```